# Return variable as a Class Object

Tags: c++

I have created a string class using a character array.

I actually to need place that array instead of class object. here's an easy example.

I want to print **A** as an integer , not **B** as a class object which isn't possible.

```
#include <iostream>

class T 
{
   int A ;

   public : T ( )
   {
       A = 10 ;
   }
} ;

void main ( )
{
    T B ;
    std :: cout << B ;
}
```

1. Is it possible?
2. Okay, but how?

Comment: `main` is required to return an `int`.

Comment: Steps to achieve your requirement: step 0: Remove Caps From The Beginning Of Each Word Because It Is Highly Annoying.

Comment: Why On Earth Do You Capitalize Each Word?

Comment: Could you please just help me instead of that ?

Comment: Overload your `operator<<` to insert `A` into the stream.

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary empty lines form the code, they make it hard to read.

Comment: I actually don't know how to overload an operator , any easier ways ?

Comment: Get into the habit of using constructor initializer lists instead of assigning to variables inside the body.

Comment: @OneBytePerHour Could you please just help us help you, instead? FWIW. My editor allowed me to fix things. Cheers.

Comment: Operator overloading is the word.

Comment: @OneBytePerHour they actually help you a lot, beyond the answer to this particular question: If you make your questinos more readable you will get answers to this *and to future questions* more likely, because people will not be turned away because their eyes burn after reading the first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

You need an output stream operator:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& o, const T& t)
{
  return o << t.A;
}
```

Note that, since `A` is private, it would have to be a `friend` of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to add a function to the public part of your class definition that returns the value of A:

```
class T{
...
public:
...
int retA(){
    return A;
}
};

int main{
T B;
cout << B.retA();
return 0;   //This is what chris said in his comment!
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that although `main` must be *declared* as returning an `int`, you don't actually need a `return` statement in its body. Unlike anywhere else in C++, this is one place that there is an implicit `return 0` if you fall through the bottom. (Weird, I know.)

Comment: @wjl: I ABHOR that rule and wish that everybody would forget it.  If I have a function that returns something then I'm going to explicitly return something, darn it!

Comment: @ wjl : Thanks for pointing that out. And after all C++ tends to always by default return a value in most cases doesn't it?

Comment: No, this only applies to the `main` function, where there is an implicit `return 0;`. What @chris meant was that you need `int main()` instead of `void main()`.